# CSS Not Reflecting in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, theme, css

I have customized Magento 2 home page using **custom theme extends from luma** theme.

While Header customization, change color **"header.wrapper"** it's not reflecting. But some other properties are working.

For Example Change **body** background color its working fine. Some properties class only not working.

Example:

I added my less file

> vendor/Themename/web/css/mycss.less.

```
  .panel.wrapper {
   background-color: green;
 }
```

This is my default.xml file:

> vendor/Themename/Magento_Theme/default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
    <css src="css/mycss.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

I am using grunt compilation, so grunt convert less to css and store to pub/static. and mycss file calling while execute this page, but not reflecting.

But I change via firebug its working fine.

Why? Suggest me how to solve this?.

Comment: which file you have modified? Is your code deployed to pub/static ?

Comment: @amitshree  I update  my question.

Comment: see this post https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/173016/best-way-to-extend-module-less-found-in-web-css-source-module-like-minicart-le/173079#173079, it has been very useful for me

Comment: did you get a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I am replying to this question, as it hadn't been answered effectively yet. 
CSS is not reflecting because there is an issue with the cache. So, to fix the issue, you have to clear the cache. To do it, run the following codes one by one:

1. `rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*`
2. `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
3. `php bin/magento cache:clean`
4. `php bin/magento cache:flush`

Answer (score 1):

Create your theme on below path given instead of vendor folder

```
app\design\frontend\vendor\themename
```

and apply theme from admin and clear cache, whenever you add new files in your theme you need to deploy static content from cmd command given below.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: I already did this its not work for me, css working fine, but when chage "header.wrapper"(home page header) its doen't work.

Answer (score 1):

-app
--design
---frontend
----VendorName
-----VendorTheme
------Magento-Theme
-------layout
--------default.xml
--------default_head_blocks.xml
------media
-------preview.png
------web
-------css
--------yourcss.css
------registration.php
------theme.xml