# Best way to extend module less found in web/css/source/module, like _minicart.less?

Tags: magento2, theme, frontend, less, extend

Which is then the best way to extend less files content in `<module>/web/css/source/module/`, like for instance `Magento_Checkout/web/css/source/module/_minicart.less`?

Assuming that to

**A) OVERRIDE**

1. **theme related less** you must create (or copy) a less with the same name of the parent theme and put it in your theme like this `theme-frontend-blank/web/css/source/_buttons.less` -> `<your-theme>/web/css/source/_buttons.less`
2. **module specific less** you must create (or copy) a less with the same name of the parent theme and put it in your theme like this `theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_module.less` -> `<your-theme>Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_module.less`
3. **UI lib less** you must create (or copy) a less with the same name content in the library folder and put it in your theme like this `magento2-base/lib/web/css/source/lib/_buttons.less` -> `<your-theme>Magento_Theme/web/css/source/lib/_buttons.less`

and to

**B) EXTEND**

1. **theme related less** you must create an _extend.less file in your theme adding *_extend* in the name like this `<your-theme>/web/css/source/_navigation_extend.less` to extend `theme-frontend-blank/web/css/source/_navigation.less` AND register that file with *@import* directive in the _extend.less of the theme content in web/css/source -> `@import "_navigation_extend.less"`
2. **module specific less** you must create an _extend.less file in your theme module path like this `<your-theme>Magento_CatalogSearch/web/css/source/_extend.less` which extends the Magento_CatalogSearch original _module.less
3. **UI lib less** you must create a less with the same name content in the library folder adding *_extend* in the name like this `<your-theme>Magento_Theme/web/css/source/lib/_buttons_extend.less` to extend `magento2-base/lib/web/css/source/lib/_buttons.less` AND register that file with *@import* directive in the _extend.less of the theme content in web/css/source -> `@import "lib/_buttons_extend.less"`

Theory must suggest you create a _minicart_extend.less but it doesn't automatically work. Maybe you should import that file in the _extend.less of that module like explained in B1 or B3?

And why these components extending less are not automatically included in the parsing of the css if this is the correct way to extend them but must be imported in the _extend.less?

(Here comes also another question: what's the differences between `web/css/source/lib/_buttons.less` and `web/css/source/_buttons.less`? )

I'm a bit confused. Hope someone could help me.

Sorry for this long text.

---

Sources:

- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-overview.html
- http://inchoo.net/magento-2/working-with-css-in-your-first-magento-2-project/comment-page-1/#comment-434125

Comment: How to find out which Magento module is customize/extended in Magento 2?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to Magento 2 conventions, the best way to extend module styles is as follows:

If we want to extend styles from `Magento_Checkout/web/css/source/module/_minicart.less` we need to have 2 files

- `<your-theme>/Magento_Checkout/web/css/source/_extend.less` where we will import our custom extensions. In this case `@import "_minicart_extend.less"`
- `<your-theme>/Magento_Checkout/web/css/source/_minicart_extend.less` that will contain our custom styles.

The reason why we need an `_extend.less` file to specify the `@imports` is because Magento only includes automatically an `_extend.less` per module. Checking and adding all `*_extend.less` automatically will be time-consuming and that is why it was not implemented like that.

In Magento Blank theme files responsible for minicart are located in
`/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Checkout/`

We could also add all our custom styles directly into the `_extend.less` . However, splitting them into smaller and specific files like in the original module keeps the code clear and better organized. That is also the recommended way according to Magento 2 standards.

Comment: Thank you @Jalogut! So, I could also call "_minicart_extend.less" as "foobar.less" and it would make no difference as it's what you @import in _extend.less that counts. Adding "_extendd.less" to component name it's just a convention to help you keep everything more clear?

Comment: Exactly, that's the idea.

Comment: @Jalogut are you sure about them saying this "Checking and adding all *_extend.less automatically will be time consuming" or it's your guess ? because IMO sure it take a little more, but not that much, as to make developers do this each time they want to customize (plus a little confusion at first)

Comment: *"The reason why we need an _extend.less file to specify the @imports is because Magento only includes automatically an _extend.less per module."*
I think you meant to say that each module has one _extend.less and they are merged to one big _extend.less file at the end

Comment: *"We could also add all our custom styles directly into the _extend.less"*
Thats a bad idea, since "grunt watch" does not listens for changes in this file. Only use it for imports and always call `grunt refresh` after you make a change in this file.

Comment: And then you want to extend a theme that already uses extends and you realize how much magento sucks again. Why can't I just @import '@parent/minicart' in my child minicart.less?