# How to add custom less file for particular page (product listing page)

Tags: magento2.2, magento2.3, less, custom-theme

I am building a custom theme in Magento and Luma theme is my parent theme. I am trying to customize the product listing page with my own style.

Here is what I did

1. I copied list.phtml from module catalog and place it under my theme `Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`
2. Add `_module.less` file under `Magento_Catalog/web/css/source/` to extend the luma product listing page 
   When I try to run the static deploy commanded, I get below error

   > [Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException]
   >
   > Cannot read contents from file
   >   "/Users/georgemm/Sites/magento2/pub/static/f
   >   rontend/George/ultimate/en_US/css/styles-m.css"
   >   Warning!file_get_contents(/
   >   Users/georgemm/Sites/magento2/pub/static/frontend/George/ultimate/en_US/css
   >
   > /styles-m.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Can you please help how to extend less file for particular page

Comment: Please find whether this solution solves your problem https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/173016/best-way-to-extend-module-less-found-in-web-css-source-module-like-minicart-le

Comment: @RajMohanR - no it's not solve, can you please help me with some examples